# mod_proxy_ajp cookie value being stripped

Tags: apache, tomcat, cookies, mod-proxy, ajp

I have a set up with apache using mod_proxy_ajp to  forward requests to a tomcat server. When the request arrives it seems to lose my values. This was working fine when the request went straight to tomcat, so it seems like apache is stripping the values.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Browser**:
    MyCookie
    value=ID=12345
    Path=/
    Domain=mydomain.org

**Tomcat**:
    MyCookie
    value=ID
    Path=null
    Domain=null

Config:

```
LoadModule proxy_module                 /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_proxy.so  
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module                 /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_proxy_ajp.so  
LoadModule rewrite_module                 /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_rewrite.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName server.domain.org  
ServerAlias server.domain.org  
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "content-type,x-requested-with"

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ /vaultWeb [PT]

<Directory />
Options All
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location />
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
</Location>

ProxyPass /app1 ajp://localhost:18009/app1
ProxyPass /app2 ajp://localhost:8009/app2
ProxyPass /app3 ajp://localhost:8009/app3
ProxyPass /app4 ajp://localhost:18009/app4
ProxyPass /app5 ajp://localhost:9008/app5
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So further investigation reveals that the equals sign is the issue. If the cookie is just the value instead of ID=thevalue, the value get's pushed through. Still an issue though because the value can have equal signs in it, and they are being stripped as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems that either apache or tomcat was 'helping' and since the cookie was version 0, any characters not approved by that spec were being removed. In this case the equals sign (and anything after it). Since I had no control over the server setting the cookie, the best I could convince them to do was encode the cookie, then I just use URLDecoder to decode the value. Boom equal signs and everything.